# Phonegap 2 + Sencha Touch2 + iOS

Tags: xcode, ios5, cordova, sencha-touch-2

This is my first question on Stack Overflow. Please be kind on my mistakes. I want to combine Sencha Touch 2 and Phonegap 2 for iOS in XCode.

Steps I took:

1. Created a Phonegap project for iOS.
2. Created a Sencha Touch 2 project separately.
3. Removed all the contents inside the `www` folder except `cordova.2.0.0.js`.
4. Copied the entire Sencha Touch 2 project contents and put it in the `www` folder of the Phonegap project.
5. Added cordova js to app.json path. [somebody told me that including that in `index.html` will not include that and it has to be done this way. Please correct me if I'm wrong.]

Result :

Sencha Touch 2 app runs fine when I run it from XCode. But the Phonegap script doesn't work. I put a simple Phonegap works alert inside html of `main.js`.

```
html: [
       "<script type='text/javascript'>",
       "document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {",
       "alert('Our first PhoneGap app');",
       "}, false);",
       "</script>",
       "You've just generated a new Sencha Touch 2 project. What you're looking at right now is the ",
       "contents of <a target='_blank' href=\"app/view/Main.js\">app/view/Main.js</a> - edit that file ",
       "and refresh to change what's rendered here."
       ].join("")
```

While the content shows, the script doesn't run. I tried [this tutorial](http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap/). But I believe it's old and doesn't cover Phonegap 2. Also I've seen Sencha built for iOS instead of Phonegap, that packs everything nicely. But I need Phonegap and its features.

Please help me with any updated tutorial, hints, code sample/download [not greedy, helpless].

Thanks all,

Prabhakar S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include cordova.js in your index.html file.

Comment: Hi I just put this in index.html ::: <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script> and the code stops working

Comment: Try adding this in the head of your index.html <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
       alert('Our first PhoneGap app');
     }, false);
        </script>

Comment: Thank you creativityhurts [No it actually helped me :)]. Your solution works at my home mac mini perfectly [mac mini - mountain lion - xcode 4.4.1]. I dont know why it didnt on my office IMAC - LION - Xcode 4.2.1....I was at my office when i asked the question. Thanks a 1000 times. So is that it, am i doing it right. I will post my update first thing tomorrow morning. Thanks again.

Comment: Great. If the solution worked for you can accept this answer and vote it up.

Comment: I am sorry for the very late reply. I accepted the answer. But I couldnt upvote as i have dont enough reputation to vote. SOrry but thanks again

Comment: Just wanted to add that this answer is correct. I was looking for a while and was expecting something more complicated but all you need to do is to include cordova.js in your index.html (as the answer says) I put the following and the code works via xcode <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>